# Is there any free toolset for generating harness for testing embedded platform?

Tags: unit-testing, embedded, automated-tests

I mean something similar to [VectorCAST](http://www.vectorcast.com/) or maybe [CANTATA++](http://www.qa-systems.com/)

What I want: I've got C code for target system I'm going to test and I've got target hardware with a little channel to developers PC (UART, tcp/ip and so on). I want software, that gives me capabilities to write tests for embedded system on a host PC on C++ and automates transfer calls of embedded code on a target system with uart etc.

I think It might be written for two weekends on [PyGCCXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygccxml/) and [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) (and [protobuf generator for embedded C](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-embedded-c/)), but maybe such system is already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Embedded Unit](http://embunit.sourceforge.net/), a unit test framework for embedded C systems.

Comment: There are plenty of frameworks for unit testing that are suitable to make test program for running on a target system. The problem with it is that target system has no room for that. Common pattern for that situation is making interface library for your target device for host PC and making tests for that library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

[Parasoft c/c++ test](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/cpptest.jsp?itemId=47)

[Embunit](http://www.embunit.com/)